# Convert HTML tags to basic formatted text for Excel

Tags: php, html, excel, str-replace, strip-tags

How can I convert HTML tags such as `<p>` and `<ol>` to basic formatted text?

A client has several data tables they want saved to CSV (ugh) that they then want to load into excel. Several of the fields have HTML tags in them including bulletted lists and paragraph tags. I'd like to either display this properly in excel (very unlikely that the client will be able to convince THEIR client to run a VBA code thing) or if it's easier use PHP to strip out all the tags and replace them with bullet point characters and line breaks.

An example of one field:

```
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
<li>Blahblahblah lots of text</li>
<li>Even more text.</li>
<li>Yet more text</li>
</ol>
```

Sorry if this has already been asked but I could only find answers for the opposite question (`bullets -> <li>`) or answers involving copious amounts of VBA and other things beyond the scope  of what I need to do or that the client's client simply won't (be able to) do.

Comment: a lot to unpack here, do you want a  CSV or excel formatted file? do you want to strip formatting or convert? you don't seem to have decided what you actually want yet

Comment: I don't WANT to do anything, I think it's all terrible, my client's client wants 6 different tables of data including many-to-many (via union tables), with some fields containing paragraphs of text, all smooshed into a dynamically-generated csv file that they then want to open in Excel with all the formatting and line breaks still in place. So I want <li> to be bullet points, <br> to be line breaks. I don't know why they want something like that when it's all available beautifully formatted on the searchable and sortable website built for them but I get paid either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strip_tags and str_replace.

Replace the `<li>` with the bullets then remove all other html tags.

```
$str ='<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
<li>Blahblahblah lots of text</li>
<li>Even more text.</li>
<li>Yet more text</li>
</ol>';

echo strip_tags(str_replace("<li>", "•", $str));


/*
•Blahblahblah lots of text
•Even more text.
•Yet more text
*/
```

https://3v4l.org/7vJuo

Comment: This works but you can't just open the file straight into Excel, I think the line breaks are breaking it. Opens properly if you open the file and then also go Data -> From Text/CSV and open the file again